# React: Invalid Hook Call Error with rc-pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-hooks

I'm working on a pagination component in React using rc-pagination and rc-select npm packages:

Example here:
https://react-component.github.io/pagination/?path=/story/rc-pagination--jumper

I'm using a class based component and everything renders perfectly unless this prop is added:

selectComponentClass={Select}

I get this error:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

---

I need this prop to render out rc-select which is a dropdown with a list of pages per page for e.g 10, 20, 50

I've also tried using a custom component with the prop for e.g selectComponentClass={CustomSelect} which doesn't work either.

I did test with a bare bones create-react-app and added rc-pagination like above and it worked so I'm not sure if there is some webpack setup I need as my project doesn't use create-react-app it's all custom.

```
import React from 'react';
import Pagination from 'rc-pagination';
import Select from 'rc-select';
import locale from 'rc-pagination/es/locale/en_US';

export interface CustomPaginationProps {
    id?: string;
    current?: number;
    total?: number;
    pageSize?: number;
    pageSizeOptions: any;
    selectOptions?: any;
}

export interface CustomPaginationState {
    current?: number;
    pageSize?: number;
    total?: number;
}

class CustomPagination extends React.Component<CustomPaginationProps, CustomPaginationState> {
    state = {
        current: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
        total: 0
    };
    
    constructor(props: CustomPaginationProps) {
        super(props);
        
        this.onHandlePaginateChange = this.onHandlePaginateChange.bind(this);
    }
    
    updatePagination(current: number, pageSize: number, total: number) {
        
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.updatePagination(this.props.current, this.props.pageSize, this.props.total);
    }
    
    onHandlePaginateChange(current: number, pageSize: number, total: number) {
        this.updatePagination(current, pageSize, this.state.total);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <Pagination
            selectComponentClass={Select}
            locale={locale}
            current={this.state.current}
            onChange={this.onHandlePaginateChange}
            pageSize={this.state.pageSize}
            pageSizeOptions={this.props.selectOptions}
            total={this.state.total}
            showQuickJumper
            showSizeChanger
            />
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomPagination;
```

---

```
<CustomPagination
    current={3}
    pageSize={5}
    total={totalItems}
    pageSizeOptions={selectOptions}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select` is probably hook and you are invoking it inside class component, which is illegal.

Comment: I thought this also but in a bare bones create-react-app project i copied the code over using a class component and it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have been passing the wrong `<Select>` Component in `selectComponentClass` props.